# Cannot Edit Files on Wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello I'm using wordpress theme livewire version 2.0, when I use the editor in theme update the edited file, for example footer.php I changed the text and add some. It is saved when I view the profile but when i look the template and look at the footer it never changed even if I delete the lines in footer.php nothing changed. Why is this happening? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try asking this question on the [Wordpress StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You should find out which file was included exactly as a footer. So if you should find the relevant template files such as index.php to see if it include footer.php as footer or any other files or just hard coded there